# Is the sentence correct? I'll be back on Monday from my leave

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I'll be back on Monday from my leave.

Comment: Or you could say *I'll be back in work on Monday*

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Ell Stack Exchange.

There's nothing wrong with the sentence presented.  But the adverbial phrase of time "on Monday" works best at the end of the sentence as follows:

I'll be back from (my) leave on Monday.

Besides, the use of the verb "be" is a bit informal in the scentence.  Instead, you can say as follows:

I'll return from leave on Monday.

I'll come back from leave on Monday.

The following sentence is quoted from The Free Dictionary:

Pete will be back from holiday next week.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s fine. You’ve split the phrase “back from my leave” into two pieces, separated by “on Monday”, and some might say that is clumsy. However, I suspect you did it that way so as to avoid having:

> I’ll be back from my leave on Monday.

The above form suffers from the ambiguity as to whether or not Monday is the day on which you will return, or the day of your leave itself. If I’m right and that is why you chose your phrasing, then I agree with your choice.